# How do I iterate through a Clojure ISeq in Java?

Tags: java, clojure

I'm calling a Clojure library from a Java program and getting back an ISeq.

How can I iterate through this in Java? It seems this ought to be straightforward, but looking at the library I can't figure out how to get a Java Iterator out of an ISeq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `clojure.lang.SeqIterator`, which implements `java.util.Iterator`.